# Include dependencies of SI project during WAR deployment

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration

I deployed a SI project as WAR in tomcat. I followed the steps as described in the link :
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/101509-best-way-to-deploy-spring-integration-projects-into-a-container-war-ejb

My SI project consist of JMS adapters for receiving and posting messages to MQ. I have Websphere MQ jars included in pom.xml as dependencies in my SI project.

In my Spring MVC project, I added my SI project as a dependency.   However I  had to again include the MQ jars in the pom.xml of the spring MVC project.

Is it possible that when I add my SI project as a dependency, all the required jars of my SI project are also included in my Spring MVC project?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the SI project does not specify `provided` or `optional` for its (e.g. MQ) dependencies, Maven should pull in its dependencies transitively into the war.